# convert play getIntList to scala List[Int] simply

Tags: scala, playframework, config

I have a Play app where I'd like to read a list of integers. The Configuration object returns `Option[java.util.List[java.lang.Integer]]` but I'd like to return the scala type `Option[List[Int]]`.
I have used `JavaConversions` to return the scala List `mylist.map(_.toList)`.

But I'm unsure about converting the underlying element type from `java.lang.Integer` to `Int` in a neat way and without using any additional libraries.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just `map` the list:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

mylist.map(_.asScala.toList.map(_.intValue))
```

(it's generally recommended to prefer `JavaConverters`, which add `toJava` and `toScala` methods, to `JavaConversions`).

Comment: Hats off to you Alexey for that lightning reply! Worked like a charm. My imperative version was embarrassing. I need to learn more about the JavaConversions/JavaConverters ...